# ¿Como hacer que al pulsar un botones se hagan distintas acciones?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-ee, java-8

Me he encontrado en un problema al hacer un programa de Java, y es que tal como tengo el codigo da igual el boton que pulse que siempre se va a ejecutar la orden del boton 1 creo que es por que estoy seleccionando mal lo que ocurre en la estructura if pero no estoy seguro. El codigo que dejo es el de la clase que se encarga de ese apartado ya que tengo que hacerlo en distintas ventanas y la anterior que un Login me funciona bien.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class MarcoEleccion extends JFrame{

public MarcoEleccion(){

    setTitle("Eleccion");
    setBounds(500,500,400,400);

    LaminaEleccion milamina=new LaminaEleccion();
    add(milamina);

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}

class LaminaEleccion extends JPanel{

public LaminaEleccion(){

    texto1=new JLabel("Selecciona una opcion");
    add(texto1);

    boton1 = new JButton("Entrada");
    boton2 = new JButton("Salida");
    boton3 = new JButton("Cerrar");
    add(boton1);
    add(boton2);
    add(boton3);
    boton1.addActionListener(evento1);
    boton2.addActionListener(evento1);
    boton3.addActionListener(evento1);

}

class EventoEleccion implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (boton1.isEnabled()){

            System.out.println("Entrada");

        }else if (boton2.isEnabled()){

            System.out.println("Salida");

        }else if (boton3.isEnabled()){



        }

    }

}

private JButton boton1;
private JButton boton2;
private JButton boton3;
private JLabel texto1;
private EventoEleccion evento1=new EventoEleccion();

}
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas identificar en el ActionEvent, que botón disparo dicho evento:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource(); //Tomas la fuente del evento

            if (boton1 == source  ){
                 //Si la fuente es igual al botón 1 -> Acción 
                System.out.println("Entrada");      
            }else if (boton2 == source ){
                //Si la fuente es igual al botón 1 -> Acción
                System.out.println("Salida");     
            }else if (boton3 == source ){
                //Si la fuente es igual al botón 1 -> Acción
            }

        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero no había caído en eso, en cuanto  pueda votar tu respuesta lo haré ya que al llevar poco tiempo en esta pagina no me lo permite.